# Manipulation of int and string types for function parameter compatability

Tags: c#, readprocessmemory

I am using a `readprocessmemory` class and have got it to work for reading through multilevel pointers and displaying the integer at the final address in label2.text.

This works where I specify the base address, (shown as "0x40000" below):

```
private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Readpointer = Trainer.ReadPointerInteger("runningprocess", 0x40000, new int[3] { 0x3, 0x4, 0x10 });
        string converted = Readpointer.ToString();
        label2.Text = converted;
```

Now instead of specifying the base address "40000", I wanted to use a function to 'find out' the base address of the process and store it in a variable and pass that as a paramater instead.  This does the first part:

```
        Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName("runningprocess"); //Get process base address
        int Base = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32(); // ""
```

Unfortunately, the `"Trainer.ReadPointerInteger"` function requires the baseaddress paramater in the form "0x40000". So I did this:

```
        string BaseAddress = "0x" + Addr.ToHex(Base); // addr.ToHex is just another function which converts the int to hex.
```

Now at the point I want to pass the variable to `ReadPointerInteger's` second paramater, and I tried this:

```
        int Readpointer = Trainer.ReadPointerInteger("runningprocess", BaseAddress, new int[3] { 0x3, 0x4, 0x10 });
        string converted = Readpointer.ToString();
        label2.Text = converted;
```

It looks like this should work, but the problem (error) is that the second parameter of the 'Trainer' function is an Int, which to my newbie eyes is weird as it isn't intuitive to me to have an input parameter which includes letters as an Int. Anyway, I am stuck here, and wonder if someone could point out how to get around the Int/String problem?

FYI, the `ReadPointerInteger` class is:

```
public static int ReadPointerInteger(string EXENAME, int Pointer, int[] Offset)
{
    int Value = 0;
    checked
    {
        try
        {
            Process[] Proc = Process.GetProcessesByName(EXENAME);
            if (Proc.Length != 0)
            {
                int Bytes = 0;
                int Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, Proc[0].Id);
                if (Handle != 0)
                {
                    foreach (int i in Offset)
                    {
                        ReadProcessMemoryInteger((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Pointer, 4, ref Bytes);
                        Pointer += i;
                    }
                    ReadProcessMemoryInteger((int)Handle, Pointer, ref Value, 4, ref Bytes);
                    CloseHandle(Handle);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        { }
    }
    return Value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0x40000 is just another name for the integer 262144. It's not a string with "0x" in it, it's an alternative syntax for writing integers, for use when base 16 is more enlightening than base 10. In particular, the following cannot be true:

> the "Trainer.ReadPointerInteger" function requires the baseaddress parameter in the form "0x40000".

It's just that addresses are usually written in hex.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  Having now taken out the conversion to string line it now works, but just to understand, int32 means up to 32 base then? since there isn't a .ToInt16 option.

Comment: No, 32 means 32 bits wide. That is, from roughly -2,000,000,000 to +2,000,000,000. (Or from 0 to roughly 4,000,000,000 for unsigned values. Exactly 2^32 different possible values, either way.) Nothing to do with the base, which is just a matter of how you write the number down.